# How do I access/store latitude and longitude from Ti.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition?

Tags: javascript, ios, geolocation, titanium, latitude-longitude

I am using Titanium Studio (3.4.1) and writing in JavaScript for iOS and Android.

I am trying to get the device's latitude and longitude and return it to a function so that I could call on that function in another module and pass it to another function.

This is geo.js and inside I am loading Ti.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition and attempting to return the lattitude to the function getLat(). And then, make it available to app.js with exports.

```
exports.getLat = function(){
Ti.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    timeout : 10000;
    return JSON.stringify(e.coords.latitude);
});
};
```

This is app.js and it checks to see which platform the app is running. It sees its an iPhone and then requires geo.getLat(). After that I want to store the latitude into the variable lat and use it later to feed it to another function as a parameter, like getWdata(lat);

```
if (Ti.Platform.osname === 'android') {
    console.log('android version\n');
    var geo = require('geo');
    var lat = geo.getLat(0);
    var lng = geo.getLng(0);
    console.log('Android Coordinates: ' + lat, lng);    
        }

else if (Ti.Platform.osname === 'iphone' || 'ipad'){
    console.log('iOS version\n');
    var geo = require('geo');
    var lat = geo.getLat();
    geo.getLat();
    console.log('iOS Coordinates: ' + lat);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use callback for accomplishing this task. The simple procedure is to pass a function (called callback) as parameter and instead using `return`; call the callback function.

Also you need not to call two methods for fetching latitude/longitude, because it can be done using one method only.

*Example below :*

***In geo.js:***

```
exports.getLatLong = function(callback){
    Ti.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e) {
        if (e.success) {
            Ti.API.info("Cords latitude" + e.coords.latitude);
            Ti.API.info("Cords longitude" + e.coords.longitude);
            callback(e.coords.latitude, e.coords.longitude);
        } else {
            alert("Unable to fetch cords");
        }
    });
};
```

***Now in app.js***, call the getLatLong function as:

```
var geo = require('geo'), lat = 0, long = 0;
geo.getLatLong(function(latitude,longitude) {
    lat = latitude;
    long = longitude;
});
```

*Note : Use `Ti.API.info` instead of `console.log`.*

Comment: So why should I use Ti.API.info instead of console.log? Don't they do the same thing?

Comment: `console.log` is not officially supported by titanium guys, it might be working now but may not in future.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
Titanium.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e) {
    if (e.success) {
        Ti.API.info("Cords longitude" + e.coords.longitude);
        Ti.API.info("Cords latitude" + e.coords.latitude);
    }
});
```